# Concatenate of Hostname in script is not working

Tags: scripts, scp

I have to concatenate the Hostname in a file name and ssh it to a machine

what i have currently is

```
scp ../output/OutputFile50.txt sarah:~/client/output/OutputFile50${HOSTNAME}.txt
```

it is working if i run it on terminal but not working if i use it in shell script.

Comment: Works fine here. Does `echo OutputFile50${HOSTNAME}.txt` work?

Comment: In which environment is the script executed?

Comment: @ClassStacker ubuntu 12.04

Comment: With "environment", I meant: In what context is the shell script executed? Such as `cron`, local startip, ...

Comment: #!/bin/sh and it worked after i passed `\hostname\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

```
scp ../output/OutputFile50.txt sarah:~/client/output/OutputFile50\`hostname\`.txt
```

the hostname enclosed in `\` is working fine